# Pytest with pyenv on MacOS

Tags: python, pytest, pyenv

I am currently using pyenv for managing my python installations and it works really fine. However I recently installed python 3.6.10 with pyenv and proceeded to create a virtualenv. When I try to run the test suite after `pip install -r requirements.txt` successfully installs, I just get a `Fatal Error` and no clue as to why it fails to run other than:

$ py.test
   ============================================================================================================ test session starts =============================================================================================================
    platform darwin -- Python 3.6.10, pytest-5.1.3, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- /Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/bin/python3.6
    cachedir: .pytest_cache
    rootdir: /Users/mbc/Yougov/BrandIndex/bb8, inifile: pytest.ini
    plugins: timeouts-1.2.1, pyfakefs-3.6, cov-2.7.1, celery-4.3.0
    setup timeout: 0.0s, execution timeout: 0.0s, teardown timeout: 0.0s
    collecting 0 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Fatal Python error: Aborted

```
Current thread 0x000000010aa88dc0 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/lib/python3.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348 in __init__
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asn1crypto/_perf/_big_num_ctypes.py", line 39 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asn1crypto/_int.py", line 56 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/asn1crypto/algos.py", line 24 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py", line 7 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7518/_backends/_jws_cryptography.py", line 12 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7518/_backends/__init__.py", line 2 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7518/jws_algorithms.py", line 14 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7518/__init__.py", line 1 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/__init__.py", line 16 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/base_client/remote_app.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/base_client/__init__.py", line 3 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/flask_client/integration.py", line 3 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/flask_client/oauth_registry.py", line 4 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/integrations/flask_client/__init__.py", line 3 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/Yougov/BrandIndex/bb8/bb8/api/server/application.py", line 12 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971 in _find_and_load
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py", line 701 in pyimport
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/doctest.py", line 417 in collect
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 247 in <lambda>
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 220 in from_call
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 247 in pytest_make_collect_report
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187 in _multicall
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 86 in <lambda>
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 92 in _hookexec
  File "/Users/mbc/.pyenv/versions/3.6.10/envs/vbb8/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286 in __call__
  ...
[1]    8473 abort      py.test
```